# How to make polymer componets responsive?

Tags: responsive-design, polymer

Im just begining to use polymer and i was testing to make a demo website using polymer components but i felt difficulty on making the pages responsive ? 
Should i use css? 
Thanks

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/material.html use that :)

Comment: If you run through the guide on the Polycasts playlist on Youtube then the resultant page is responsive. Would need a bit more details about what you are finding is not responsive to answer accurately.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you could use CSS. However, web components can be a bit tricky to get responsive because of their nature of re-use and possibly different locations.

Unfortunately, while CSS/media-queries are one solution, it's not the perfect solution. Why? Because the same component, depending on it's location/container may be desired to look/behave differently. For instance, a "voting" component in a primary content section (800PX wide) may display additional information vs the same component in a right rail (200PX wide) where just the question/answers may be displayed.

What we as web developers really need are "element queries", which allow components to react based on their occupying space (rather than the page-level layout). There are articles and polyfills regarding this that may be of interest to you. One can be found here:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/

Answer (score -1):

IMO, you should focus on Web instead of Mobile, because the native Android browsers before Android 4.4 doesn't support Polymer, even with Polyfills!

Anyway there is a core-drawer-panel, which is a responsive layout you can start with.

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drawer-panel

Comment: Look im trying to build a website using polymer components,and not an android app, dont know if explained well.Thanks for the link